# How put NetBeans on redhat?

Tags: html, web-services, jsp, servlets, web

I'm try to build some html, jsp, java(servlet) and database Mysql in Netbeans, I just created a account for redhat, how can I move the NetBeans on redhat and the MySQL too.

I did not find any way on searching related content.

What should I do to host the server on redhat, rather than from my pc local.

Comment: Try reading the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/).

Comment: I only can find mysql for database , but for the language (java,js,net,perl,ruby,ruby.php,python)... Where is the jsp (java ?) but seem some different... can anoyone give me more details please? and how to connect the jsp to mysql db that setup on redhat??? and even html, i cannot found on the redhat...

Comment: can anyone give me a tutorial or set of instruction for setup a basic web-apps(jsp , mysql) on redhat please